# Selecting row based on a column variation

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a file, named `any_csv.csv`, containing...

```
A,B,random
1,2,300
3,4,300
5,6,300
1,2,300
3,4,350
8,9,350
4,5,350
5,6,320
7,8,300
3,3,300
```

I wish to keep all the rows, where `random` variates/changes.
I made this little program to achieve this, but, as I wish to learn more about pandas and as my program is slower than I expect it to be (~130 seconds to process a 1.2 million line log file), I ask for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('any_csv.csv')
mask = np.zeros(len(df.index), dtype=bool)

#   Initializing my current value for comparison purposes.
mask[0] = 1
previous_val = df.iloc[0]['random']
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['random'] != previous_val:
        #   If a variation has been detected, switch to True current, and previous index.
        previous_val = row['random']
        mask[index] = 1
        mask[index - 1] = 1

#   Keeping the last item.
mask[-1] = 1

df = df.loc[mask]
df.to_csv('any_other_csv.csv', index=False)
```

I guess that in short, I wish to know how to apply my if, in this homemade for-loop, that is averall pretty slow.

Results :

```
A,B,random
1,2,300
1,2,300
3,4,350
4,5,350
5,6,320
7,8,300
3,3,300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with 2 masks for check different values with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal:

```
df = df[df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift()) | df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift(-1))]
print (df)
   A  B  random
0  1  2     300
3  1  2     300
4  3  4     350
6  4  5     350
7  5  6     320
8  7  8     300
9  3  3     300
```

For better verifying:

```
df['mask1'] = df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift()) 
df['mask2'] = df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift(-1))
df['mask3'] = df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift()) | df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift(-1))
print (df)
   A  B  random  mask1  mask2  mask3
0  1  2     300   True  False   True
1  3  4     300  False  False  False
2  5  6     300  False  False  False
3  1  2     300  False   True   True
4  3  4     350   True  False   True
5  8  9     350  False  False  False
6  4  5     350  False   True   True
7  5  6     320   True   True   True
8  7  8     300   True  False   True
9  3  3     300  False   True   True
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 1000

In [157]: %timeit orig(df)
56.8 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [158]: %timeit (df[df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift()) | 
df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift(-1))])
939 µs ± 7.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#jpp solution - a bit slowier
In [159]: %timeit df[(df['random'] != df['random'].shift()) | (df['random'] != df['random'].shift(-1))]
1.11 ms ± 8.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
N = 10000

In [160]: %timeit orig(df)
538 ms ± 3.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [161]: %timeit (df[df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift()) | df['random'].ne(df['random'].shift(-1))])
1.16 ms ± 75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#jpp solution - a bit slowier
In [162]: %timeit df[(df['random'] != df['random'].shift()) | (df['random'] != df['random'].shift(-1))]
1.28 ms ± 8.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'random':np.random.randint(2, size=N)})
print (df)


def orig(df):
    mask = np.zeros(len(df.index), dtype=bool)

#   Initializing my current value for comparison purposes.
    mask[0] = 1
    previous_val = df.iloc[0]['random']
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['random'] != previous_val:
            #   If a variation has been detected, switch to True current, and previous index.
            previous_val = row['random']
            mask[index] = 1
            mask[index - 1] = 1

    #   Keeping the last item.
    mask[-1] = 1

    return df.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create a mask of Boolean values. The Boolean mask indicates when a value is different to a value above or below it within the series.

You can then apply the Boolean mask to your dataframe directly.

```
mask = (df['random'] != df['random'].shift()) | \
       (df['random'] != df['random'].shift(-1))

df = df[mask]

print(df)

   A  B  random
0  1  2     300
3  1  2     300
4  3  4     350
6  4  5     350
7  5  6     320
8  7  8     300
9  3  3     300
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:`

```
df.groupby(["A", "Random"]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] == 1)
```